# Typescript Compile Exclude Folders but Keep Imports

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsc

I have an express Typescript app that is the backend for my webapp. The general root structure of the app is

```
- client
    - tsconfig.json
    - React code
- server
    - application.ts
    - tsconfig.json
```

I need to compile the server files so that I can run `ts-node app.ts`. The problem is running `tsc` compiles all of the files in the root directory and not just the `server` directory. I know I could use `exclude` in the tsconfig, but in `app.ts` I have type definitions that are imported from `front-end`. Is there anyway to only compile the files in the `server` directory while being able to keep the imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to separate your TypeScript type definitions into separate files so that they don't depend on your code. By convention, the *.d.ts file extension is used for this.

I suggest that you make another folder for type definitions and move it so it is a sibling of the `server` and `client` folders. This way it can be included both in the frontend and backend compilation. However, do think twice before sharing type definitions between your frontend and backend- it can sometimes be the wrong choice if your backend objects need to store more complex logic and your frontend doesn't need to.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great suggestion! I hadn't even though of ```.d.ts``` files, but that's what I'm looking for.